# Aggregate results when using Kubeflow Pipelines kfp.ParallelFor

Tags: kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

What is a good pattern for aggregating the results from Kubeflow Pipleine kfp.ParallelFor?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you asked for, but our workaround was to write the results of the parallelfor tasks into S3 and simply collect them afterwards in a postprocessing task.

```
with dsl.ParallelFor(preprocessing_task.output) as plant_item:
                predict_plant='{}'.format(plant_item)
                forecasting_task = forecasting_op(predict_plant, ....).after(preprocessing_task)
postprocessing_task = postprocessing_op(...).after(forecasting_task)
```

Comment: (After multiple suggested edits: no, the postprocessing step is _not_ inside the loop, it is afterwards. That is exactly what collects the results.)

Comment: Are you aware of any documentation supporting that? When I try to recreate this approach, one `postprocessing_task` node appears in the graph for each of my `forecasting_task` equivalents.

Comment: Did you put plant_item or predict_plant as input into it? Because then it's understandable. But no, documentation I couldn't find, just trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment this might not be supported:

[Support inputs with multiple arguments #1933](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/issues/1933)